# Spring data JPA - Map object returned from native query to a POJO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have scenario where I want to mapped data fetched from native query in a JPA repository to custom object.

My repository code is as follows:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,name = "TopCouponOffer")
List<TopCouponOffer> findTodayTopOffer(@Param("date") String date, @Param("time") String time);
```

My custom class code is as follows:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "TopCouponOffer",
    query =
           "SELECT c.id,c.code\n" +
                   " FROM COUPON c \n" +
                   "JOIN CLICK cl\n" +
                   "ON cl.coupon_id = c.id\n" +
                   "JOIN COUPONS_STATUS cs\n" +
                   "ON cs.id= c.coupons_status_id\n" +
                   "JOIN COUPONS_OFFER_TYPE ct\n" +
                   " ON ct.id= c.coupons_offer_types_id\n" +
                   "WHERE\n" +
                   " c.ongoing_offer = 1 AND\n" +
                   " c.coupons_status_id != 4 AND\n" +
                   "IF(:date < c.end_date,\n" +
                   "             IF(:date < c.start_date,\n" +
                   "                 0,\n" +
                   "                 IF(:date = c.start_date,\n" +
                   "                     IF(:time < c.start_time,\n" +
                   "                         0,\n" +
                   "                         1),\n" +
                   "                     1)),\n" +
                   "             IF(:date = c.end_date || :date = c.start_date, \n" +
                   "                IF(:time > c.end_time || :time < c.start_time,\n" +
                   "                         0,\n" +
                   "                         1), 0)) = 1 ORDER BY cl.count DESC LIMIT 2",
    resultSetMapping = "TopCouponOffer",
    resultClass = TopCouponOffer.class
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="TopCouponOffer",
        classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = TopCouponOffer.class,columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "code")
        })
        }
)
public class TopCouponOffer {
    Integer id;
    String code;
    public TopCouponOffer(Integer id, String code){
       this.id=id;
       this.code=code;
   }
}
```

But I am getting the following error when running the application

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findTodayTopOffer found for type Coupon!

Should I moved name query and sqlresultmapping to my entity class? Thing is that I don't wanna pollute my entity class is there any way I can achieve that with adding more code to my entity class?

Comment: Why don't you use criteria API ? Native Queries must only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your functionname in the repository should be renamed to findByDateAndTime.